# Is it possible to use Retrofit to call ASP.NET Web API from an Android Application without using emulator?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, retrofit

For memory reasons I can't use emulator. If I create an ASP.NET Web API project in Visual Studio 2015. Can I call API from my Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your web API to a web hosting company available online which supports windows IIS server for ASP.NET sites. There are many web hosting company that gives you free trial, I personally like [MyWindowshosting](http://www.mywindowshosting.com) which gives you free 60 days trial. So you can deploy it and test you Web API before going to production.

For testing purpose you can also access a locally deployed web api using IP address as long as your device is on same network. Hope this helps! Happy coding!

Comment: Actually, as long as the Android device is on the same network as your API server, (e.g. Wifi), you should be able to access it - external hosting should not be necessary. Of course, the Android application will have to access the API using it's IP address instead of a domain name.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yah its also possible as long as device is on same network.

Comment: Is it possible to access local machine from my android device  without internet connection?

Comment: Yes, both devices should share same network say your home wifi or any hotspot